# Moving a recyclerviewer to different tab

Tags: java, android

I have 3 fragment(Todo, Ongoing , Finished)

A recyclerviewer populates the first fragment (ToDO). I want to move the recyclerview to the next tab (ongoing). Could not find appropriate documentation on this. Below is a screenshot of the UI

[image: board]

Code for adapter

```
public class recyclerKanbanAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerKanbanAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<kanbanItems> kanlist;
    Context context;
    public recyclerKanbanAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<kanbanItems>kanbanList)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.kanlist=kanbanList;
    }

    public recyclerKanbanAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_itemkanban,parent,false);
        return new recyclerKanbanAdapter.MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull recyclerKanbanAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        kanbanItems kanban = kanlist.get(position);
        holder.contractorName.setText(kanban.getContractorName());
        holder.Duration.setText(kanban.getDuration());
        holder.taskName.setText(kanban.getTaskName());
        holder.btn_Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                kanlist.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(), kanlist.size());
            }
        });
        holder.btn_Move.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //move to next tab
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return kanlist.size();
    }
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        EditText taskName,Duration,contractorName;
        ImageButton btn_Delete;
        ImageButton btn_Move;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            btn_Move=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_move);
            btn_Delete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
            taskName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTaskName);
            Duration=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDuration);
            contractorName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtContractor);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I want to move the recyclerview to the next tab (ongoing)` so what are you struggling with ?

Comment: how can i move it to the next tab?

Comment: that was not my question, i'm asking what are you struggling with ? what is a tab, is it another fragment or is it another layout ?

Comment: im struggling to move it:(todo.xml) to the next fragment (doing.xml)